# Do I need SSL for forums

Tags: security

I'm going to be setting up forums on my website. I will be using [MyBB client](http://www.mybb.com/). Do I really need SSL to protect my visitors username, password and email address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is best practice to use SSL when you are collecting information from users. If you don't all your data will be visible in plain text and if someone is sniffing the connection, they will see everything.

Answer (score 1):

Do you **need** it to run a forum?  No.  But, since you mention you would like for protect your visitors' username, password, and email address (good on you), then I would highly recommend using TLS/SSL.

A more complete answer is provided here: [Do I need SSL Cert for simple community site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282762/do-i-need-ssl-cert-for-simple-community-site)

Answer (score 0):

“Really need” is subjective. But SSL encryption is definitely a good practice – moreso now than when the question was originally asked.

I’m assuming you’re referring to [TLS and not SSL](https://www.incapsula.com/cdn-guide/cdn-and-ssl-tls.html), but SSLs ensure secure connections are established between your server and the user’s browser and all traffic is encrypted. Who wants passwords to leak?

The other important thing is that [browsers now display warning signs](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/xygdxq/google-will-soon-shame-all-websites-that-are-unencrypted-chrome-https) to sites that don’t use SSL, so for the 90% of times that everything will be fine, your user left because they were warned that your site is unsafe. Google is also penalizing sites that don’t use HTTPS with lower search rankings.